# Live Charts WPF Unknown build error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, livecharts

I'm new to live charts. When i'm trying to build a simple WPF application using visual studio 2017 i'm getting the following error:

Error Unknown build error, 'A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044) Line 11 Position 67.'

EDIT:

The code is:

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" />
```

According to the docs.

How can i solve this issue?

Thanks

EDIT 2:

fixed after VS reinstall.

Comment: Without the error context it will be hard to help. What does Line 11 Position 67 refer to?

Comment: @riQQ please see my edit.

Comment: Are you trying to sign your assembly?

Comment: What do you mean by sing the assembly?
I installed the LiveCharts.WPF NuGet package -> set a simple chart and build the solution.

Comment: Check the signing tab of your project properties

Comment: Thanks @riQQ, I tried to create a new key but is still trowes build errors. So I still didn't figure how to create a signing key that will match LiveCharts.. :-\

Comment: Can you please post the section of your .csproj file that references LiveCharts and LiveCharts.Wpf